# dynamic 2d char array in c

Tags: c++, c

I want to take username and passwords from client and check that this username already didn't exist, but it doesn't work and this error happens:

> Exception thrown at 0x51D20ED2 (ucrtbased.dll) in project3.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDCD.>

I don't know why?

This is my code:

```
void signup(char *input, char **usernames,int *userindex,char **passwords)
{
    int check = 0;
    char *ptr1,*ptr2;
    ptr1 = (char*)malloc(strlen(input)*sizeof(char));
    ptr2 = (char*)malloc(strlen(input)*sizeof(char));
    strtok(input, " ");
    strcpy(ptr1, strtok(NULL," "));
    strcpy(ptr2, strtok(NULL," "));
    for (int i = 1; i < *(userindex); i++)
    {
        if (!(strcmp(ptr1,usernames[i])))
        {
            check = 1;
            printf("this user has already signed up\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (check == 0)
    {
        usernames[*(userindex)] = (char*)malloc((strlen(ptr1))* sizeof(char));
        passwords[*(userindex)] = (char*)malloc((strlen(ptr2))* sizeof(char));
        strcpy(usernames[*(userindex)], ptr1);
        strcpy(passwords[*(userindex)], ptr2);
        printf("%s\n%s\n%d\n", usernames[*(userindex)], passwords[*(userindex)], *(userindex));
        *(userindex) = *(userindex)+1;
        free(ptr1);
        free(ptr2);
    }
}


int main()
{
    int quit = 0;
    char *input, **usernames, **passwords;
    int state, length, userindex = 1;
    usernames = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    passwords = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    while (quit == 0)
    {
        int counter = 1;
        char buffer;
        input = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
        printf("please enter your action\n");
        do
        {
            buffer = getchar();
            input = (char*)realloc(input, counter*sizeof(char));
            input[counter - 1] = buffer;
            counter++;
        } while (buffer != '\n');
        input = (char*)realloc(input, (counter)*sizeof(char));
        input[counter - 1] = '\0';
        state = action_decider(input);
        switch (state)
        {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                usernames = (char**)realloc(usernames,userindex*sizeof(char*)); 
                passwords = (char**)realloc(passwords,userindex*sizeof(char*)); 
                signup(input, usernames, &(userindex), passwords);
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                quit = 1;
                break;
            case 7:
                printf("you command nonsence!\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: " this errorhappens" ?? what error

Comment: Show the code that calls `signup`. The origin of the problem may be there.

Comment: Actually we need a [MCVE]. Showing only the code that calls `signup` may not be enough.

Comment: `usernames[*(userindex)] = (char*)malloc((strlen(ptr1))* sizeof(char));` --> `usernames[*(userindex)] = (char*)malloc((strlen(ptr1)+1)* sizeof(char));` The same for `ptr2`

Comment: Access violation in the argument of (if)

Comment: this is the my main
#define DEBUG
int main()

Comment: @ahoora.mozaffari where is your main ? Please read this: [mcve].

Comment: {
 int quit = 0;
 char *input, **usernames, **passwords;
 int state, length, userindex = 1;
 usernames = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
 passwords = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
 while (quit == 0)
 {
  int counter = 1;
  char buffer;
  input = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
  printf("please enter your action\n");
  do
  {
   buffer = getchar();
   input = (char*)realloc(input, counter*sizeof(char));
   input[counter - 1] = buffer;
   counter++;
  } while (buffer != '\n');
  input = (char*)realloc(input, (counter)*sizeof(char));
  input[counter - 1] = '\0';

Comment: state = action_decider(input);switch (state)
  {
  case 0:

   break;
  case 1:

   break;
  case 2:

   break;
  case 3:

   break;
  case 4:
   usernames = (char**)realloc(usernames,userindex*sizeof(char*));
   passwords = (char**)realloc(passwords,userindex*sizeof(char*));
   signup(input, usernames, &(userindex), passwords);
   break;
  case 5:

   break;
  case 6:
   quit = 1;
   break;
  case 7:
   printf("you command nonsence!\n");
   break;
  }
 }
 return 0;
}

Comment: Edit your post. Do not post code as comment..

Comment: @ahoora.mozaffari your copy/paste operation removed some `*` chars. For exampel `countersizeof(char)` should be `counter*sizeof(char)`. I've fixed all those problems here, now your code compiles, but there are plenty of warnings such as `'=': 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'` , or `'realloc': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1`. Fix all warnings and post your actual code.

Comment: @LPs did you read the comment why I added the *s? Look at ahoora.mozaffari's comment, why is the part `usernames, **passwords; int state, length, userindex = 1; usernames = (char` bold? Because the * before and afterwards was interpreted as markdown format and so they were not visible when you copy/paste the code into the question.

Comment: @mch Yes, you right. I didn't read it.

Comment: The function `signup()` crashes if `input` doesn't contain three tokens (to be returned by `strtok()`). What did you enter after the prompt `please enter your action`?

Comment: What is `action_decider`?